i cannot for the life of me get the joint_trajectory_controller to configure and load correctly in ROS2
this is my first post and the first time i thought of asking for help. I am trying to get the joint_trajectory_controller  to load with a proper configuration. my launch file tells it where the urdf is and the yaml but it won't configure. I am trying to connect to a Franka Research 3 robotic arm and it's killing me.
here is my launch file:
from launch import LaunchDescription

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
def generate_launch_description():
return LaunchDescription([
    # Declare launch arguments (robot IP and arm ID)
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'robot_ip', default_value='192.168.1.11',
        description='Hostname or IP address of the robot.'),
    
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'arm_id', default_value='fr3',
        description='ID of the type of arm used (e.g., fr3).'),
    
    # Node to publish the robot's state using the URDF
    Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': open('/home/charisma/franka_ros2_ws/src/franka_ros2/joint_trajectory_controller/src/fr3_output.urdf').read()}],
    ),
    
    # Controller manager node to manage robot controllers
    Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        name='ros2_control_node',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[
            '/home/charisma/franka_ros2_ws/src/franka_ros2/joint_trajectory_controller/src/controllers.yaml',  # Path to controllers.yaml
            {'robot_description': open('/home/charisma/franka_ros2_ws/src/franka_ros2/joint_trajectory_controller/src/fr3_output.urdf').read()},
            {'arm_id': 'fr3'},
        ],
        remappings=[('joint_states', 'franka/joint_states')],
    ),
    
    # Spawner for the joint state broadcaster
    Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster'],
        output='screen',
    ),
    
    # Spawner for the joint trajectory controller
    Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_trajectory_controller'],
        output='screen',
    ),
    
    # Optional: Load the Franka gripper but don’t enable it until ready
    Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['franka_gripper_controller'],
        output='screen',
        condition=None,  # Disable gripper for now
    ),
])

this is my URDF:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<ros2_control>

franka_hardware/FrankaHardware



<!-- Define control interfaces for all joints -->
<joint name="fr3_joint1">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint2">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint3">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint4">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint5">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint6">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_joint7">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_finger_joint1">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fr3_finger_joint2">
  <command_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="position"/>
  <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>

</ros2_control>

and this is my yaml:
controller_manager:

ros__parameters:
update_rate: 1000  # Optional: Set the update rate for the controller manager
# Joint trajectory controller (for position control)
joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - fr3_joint1
    - fr3_joint2
    - fr3_joint3
    - fr3_joint4
    - fr3_joint5
    - fr3_joint6
    - fr3_joint7

  command_interfaces:
    - position  # Position control interface

  state_interfaces:
    - position
    - velocity

  action_monitor_rate: 20.0
  allow_partial_joints_goal: false
  constraints:
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01
    goal_time: 0.0
    fr3_joint1:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint2:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint3:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint4:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint5:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint6:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03
    fr3_joint7:
      trajectory: 0.05
      goal: 0.03

# Joint state broadcaster (publishes joint states for monitoring)
joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

# Franka robot state broadcaster (publishes detailed robot state)
franka_robot_state_broadcaster:
  type: franka_robot_state_broadcaster/FrankaRobotStateBroadcaster

I am running out of time and i need to figure this out. I an undergraduate at Oregon State University working in the robotics lab and my phd mentor is kind of stringing me along. I haven't taken any of the advance robotics classes and i am a little out of my league but i learned a lot about urdf, xacro, yaml, and launch files the past few days i am just struggling.
